# Trigger error while executing the trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

While creating a trigger iam getting error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
UPDATE rm 
        SET 
            rm.cost_sqft = isnull((
                select case when (rm.rm_cat in ('8','NON-REPORT') and rm.space_fee = 'No') then '0' else rent_w.w*@rental_rate end 
                from @rental_weight as rent_w, bl, rm            
                where rm.main_contact=rent_w.space_type
                and rm.description=rent_w.space_quality
                and bl.cost_type = rent_w.campuse_cost      
                and bl.bl_id = rm.bl_id
            ),'0') 
                WHERE rm.bl_id=@bl_id
        AND rm.fl_id=@fl_id
        AND rm.rm_id=@rm_id 

        FETCH NEXT FROM rm_cost
        INTO @bl_id, @fl_id, @rm_id         
    END
```

Comment: The message is fairly self-explanatory. Have you tried running the subquery on its own to see why it's returning more data than you expect?

Comment: hey Nick iam new to this and unable to resolve the error

Comment: The error says your select statement has returned more than one record for the condition in the where clause. Now mysql does not know which one to update and asking you to help it my limiting the result of the select statement to only one per condition.

Comment: Not directly related to the question but I would expect to see reference to NEW. and/or OLD.values in a trigger and  would not expect a cursor.

Comment: I have this database room and building table. I have more fields, but these are the one I want a trigger. How can I create a trigger for the situation? 
Auto populate the rm.cost_common_services and rm.cost_sqft fields except when (rm.cat = 8 or NON-REPORT) AND (rm.space_fee = ‘No’ or rm.outgoing_fee = ‘No’). 

Implementation notes: 
The rm.cost_common_services and rm.cost_sqft values will be updated by the [afm].[icat_rm_space_cost_calc] trigger when new room record is inserted or one of the following room fields is updated:

Comment: • rm (rm_cat ,outgoing_fee ,space_fee ,main_contact ,Description, rm_id, bl_id )
• bl (cost_type, bl_id)

Column name: rm.cost_common_services 
Value = base_rate * weight 
where base_rate = 193.06982 and weight value

Comment: Column name: rm.cost_sqft 
Value = base_rate * weight 
where base_rate = 192.65297 and weight value

Comment: 'when new room record is inserted' - to where? and what part does the table building play in this, and is rm and room the same table. You could hugely improve this question by including sample date from room and building together with an insert statement and your expected result after the trigger executes.BTW you cannot have s single trigger that actions on insert or update you need separate insert and update triggers but without seeing what you are trying to do I cannot say whether these should be before or after triggers.